# Reflection of Laplacian eigenfunction

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to prove a reflection principle for Laplacian eigenfunctions.

Let $OX$ denote the $x$-axis.

Let $U$ be some open, bounded subset of the plane symmetric in $OX$ and $L = OX \cap U$ a line segment; denote by $U^{+}$ a part of $U$ lying in the upper half-plane.

Function $f$ is continuous on $U^{+} \cup L$ and satisfies the two conditions:

$\Delta f = \lambda f$ on $U^{+}$ (for some constant $\lambda$),

$f = 0$ on $L$.

Then $f$ can be extended to a function $\tilde{f}$ on $U$ by defining $\tilde{f}(x,y) = f(x,y)$ for $y\geqslant 0$ and $\tilde{f}(x,y) = -f(x,-y)$ for $y < 0$. $\tilde{f}$ is supposed to satisfy $\Delta \tilde{f} = \lambda \tilde{f}$ on the whole set $U$.

Of course, we need to show the condition only for points on $L$.

What I have, are only trivial observations: $\frac{\partial^2\tilde{f}}{\partial^2 x} = 0$ on $L$ (zero values), and that if $\frac{\partial^2\tilde{f}}{\partial^2 y}$ existed on $L$, it must be equal to $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\tilde{f}(x,h)-2\tilde{f}(x,0)+\tilde{f}(x,-h)}{h^2} = 0$.

So what I need to show is the existence of $\frac{\partial^2\tilde{f}}{\partial^2 y}$ on $L$. Does that require some advanced regularity criteria?

Comment: I think the usual way to do this is to go through weak solutions (integration by parts). You show that weakly, you still have $\Delta f = \lambda f$ and then interior regularity tells you that the equation is satisfied pointwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answer: the topic is covered in: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02410764

In this case, consider $g(x,y,z)$ defined as $g(x,y,z) = f(x,y) s(z)$, where $s(z) = \cos(z \sqrt{\lambda})$ if $\lambda \geqslant 0 $ and $s(z) = \exp(z \sqrt{-\lambda})$ otherwise.

$g$ turns out to be a harmonic function on $U^{+} \times \mathbb{R}$, and the conclusion follows from the Schwartz reflection principle for harmonic functions.